# What is the absolute fastest package/software to multiply sparse * dense matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, algebra

I've tried matlab, but unfortunately it is not threaded. I've also tried eigen and although it is threaded and scales quite well, the single thread performance is a little worse than Matlab.

How can I multiply a general large sparse * dense matrix in the fastest way possible on the CPU (not GPU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both. For a single threaded environment, run `matlab` routines, for multi-threaded, go with `eigen`. And keep tabs on new developments because for highly competitive fields like these, any advice you get here will be out of date in a month.